# Jenkins - Save data to a properties file which can be accessible to all jobs

Tags: jenkins, properties, jenkins-plugins

I have 5 jobs in Jenkins which are interrelated(I trigger downstream jobs, once the upstream ones are successful). I want to save information to a properties file which can be made accessible to all the downstream jobs.

A properties file to which I can write and read data and the one which is accessible to all the Jenkins jobs. Does Jenkins provide any plugin or is there a way to do that?

Comment: Am using EnvInject plugin from which I can load all properties to InjectedEnvVariables txt file which is created under each job. Am just wondering how to use that in other jobs

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin):

> The parameters section can contain a combination of one or more of the following:
>
> - a set of predefined properties
> - properties from a properties file read from the workspace of the triggering build
> - the parameters of the current build

If you don't want to have upstream/downstream relationship between jobs, you can copy files with [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

Comment: This kind of passes the properties from upstream to downstream jobs, kind of what I am doing now. But what if job 4 wanted build properties concerned to job 1 and there is no direct relation between job 1 &4. I was just thinking if there was a way we can save all properties in one single file.

Comment: @AnujBalan Oh, got it now. What about [Copy artifacts from another project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)?